# Rock covers of Wagner's music

Tags: classical-music, rock, cover, prog-rock, opera

I am looking for rock/prog rock/jazz covers or interpretations of music written by Richard Wagner (except the ride of the valkyries). There are a lot of musicians that have made very interesting electrical versions of classical music, like Alice Coltrane's Excerpts from the Firebird, Hubert Laws' Rite of Spring, or most music of Emerson, Lake and Palmer.

I find it a bit odd that there are so few renditions of Wagner's works (except the ride of the valkyries) since there are many pieces that would suit such an interpretation.

Are there any such songs out there?

Answer (score 1):

You may enjoy the arrangements made by the Uri Caine ensemble released on [this live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner_e_Venezia). They don't fit any of your genre recommendations exactly, but they're interesting arrangements nonetheless.

You can hear the tracks in [this YouTube playlist](https://youtu.be/zG1J4rNZ-tM).

Lastly, you may be interested in the term "[Wagnerian rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagnerian_rock)."